# $A^{\top}A = (A^{\top}A)^2$ mistake

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I ended up making a mistake trying to re-derive the singular value decomposition. Here are the steps to recreate my mistake

\begin{align*}
A & \in \mathbb{R}^{n \, \times \, m} \\
AA^{\top}u_i &= \lambda_i u_i && \text{Some eigenvalue of } AA^{\top} \\
A^{\top}AA^{\top}u_i &= \lambda_i \underbrace{A^{\top} u_i}_{\text{eigenvector of } A^{\top} A} && \text{Left-multiplying by } A^{\top} \\
V & = A^{\top} U && \text{Where } U_{*i}, V_{*i} \text{ are the } i\text{-th  eigenvectors of } AA^{\top}\text{, } A^{\top}A \text{, respectively.}  \\
A^{\top}A & = V \Lambda V^{\top} && \text{By spectral theorem for symmetric matrices} \\
& = A^{\top}U \Lambda U^{\top} A \\
& = A^{\top} A A^{\top} A \\
& = (A^{\top}A)^2 && \text{There's no way that's right}
\end{align*}
The $U_{*i}$ notation means the $i$-th column of $U$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: At some point, you must have made an idempotence assumption.

Comment: @Axoren can you elaborate?

Comment: @Axoren $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^{\top}$, not of $A$.

Comment: @N.S. I realized that after the fact. I don't recall if my comment edit made it through, but I don't see my comment anymore.

Comment: @Axoren You can only edit comments for 5 minutes. After that you can only delete. You probably hit the delete button thinking it is edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices here
$$
A^{\top}A  = V \Lambda V^{\top} \\
A^{\top}U \Lambda U^{\top} A = A^{\top}A A^{\top} A$$
$U,V$ are assumed to be orthogonal matrices, which is not compatible in general with 
$$V=A^{\top}U$$

**Added:** In fact, if $U,V$ can be chosen to be orthogonal, then 
$$A^{\top}=VU^{\top}\\
A^{\top}A=VU^{\top}UV^{\top}=I_n
$$

Comment: So my mistake was assuming that symmetric matrices always decompose into $S=Q\Lambda Q^{\top}$?

Comment: @michaelsnowden No, that is always true. Your mistake was to assume that you can pick any matrix of eigenvectors to make $Q$. $Q$ needs to have normalized eigenvectors as columns.

Comment: I think I understand now. I can choose the columns of $U$ to be normalized, but because I wrote $V = A^{\top} U$, the columns of $V$ are not necessarily normalized, right?

Comment: @michaelsnowden Exactly.